# How to simulate number of occurences over a time period

Tags: python, statistics, poisson

I have an event which happens on average once every x seconds.  In Python, I wish to "simulate" a specific time interval of t seconds, and obtain a reasonable randomly sampled integer n which denotes the number of times the event happened in that time period.

How can I achieve this?

(And no, before you ask, this is not my homework, and I'm asking the experienced statistician-coders on here instead of working out exactly which combination of scipy.stats.poisson calls I need so I can get on with something else in the meantime.)

Comment: Without specifying the probability distribution this question can't be properly answered. Should we deduce from the part in parentheses that it is a poisson distribution?

Comment: I don't agree the question can't be answered properly without the distribution being specified.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this using `numpy.random.poisson` to get the samples:

```py
import numpy as np

def simulate_events(average_interval, time_period):
    average_events = time_period / average_interval
    return np.random.poisson(average_events)

average_interval = 10 # average time between events, in seconds
time_period = 60 # time period to simulate, in seconds
n = simulate_events(average_interval, time_period)
print(n)
```